# Where can I watch Sword Art Online Ordinal Scale?

Tags: sword-art-online

Sword Art Online the movie Ordinal Scale has already been released according to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Art_Online_The_Movie:_Ordinal_Scale), but I can't find it anywhere. So where can I watch and download legally.

Comment: Dear close voters: notice that the second line of this question says "legally". That means this question is not requesting illegal copyrighted materials. If there is nowhere to watch or download legally, the answer is that there is nowhere to watch or download legally, but that does not make the question off-topic.

Comment: i doubt you'll be able to download it. also the "release" date is when it was played in cinemas like how with a series the initial release date is when it first aired. generally when it comes to movies this initial release date much much earlier than the home release (where the anime is released on DVD)

Comment: I'd imagine that crunchyroll,netflix,hulu and youtube would get it eventually. But at the point of release if it's not at a theater near you then the only legal way would be to play the waiting game.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, the only place you can see it at the moment is in a theatre, as it hasn't been released on disc yet. Once it releases on disc, you can then either buy it from a shop or use a legal streaming service like Netflix if it gets released there. TV channel also play anime sometimes, so you might be able to find it there too soon.

Answer (score 1):

As of the time of this answer's writing (July 2019), Ordinal Scale is available both subtitled and dubbed on Hulu in the U.S., as well as on Steam (because Steam has anime for some reason).